# How to solve ADT dependencies on Eclipse Classic Indigo 3.7.1?

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-indigo

I want to install Android SDK on Eclipse Classic Indigo (Version: 3.7.1 Build id: M20110909-1335) Windows 7 32 bit.

On adding ADT plugin to in software update I got following some dependency error.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)

I consulted some blogs and found that I have to update my Eclipse. Following two sources are there in Eclipse.

- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7
- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

But their download is also broken. They try to dowload content.jar file which is not there.

[image]

Any hand how to solve this problem? Or I should use some other version of Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: For Android development I'd recommend installing Eclipse Java package. It comes with all Java stuff preconfigured. I have no problem using above links.

Comment: I am having the same setup on Ubuntu 11.10. And that's working. But 404 on content.jar makes sense for that problem. Can you point out that package? Or update URL?

Comment: Proxy settings problem in Eclipse?

Comment: thanks Marcin you point me towards a thing that solved this problem. I was running a anonymity proxy. I closed that application and my sdk installed. If you post your this comment as answer, i will accept your answer.

Comment: my answer is too simple to score points for it ;) Edit your question, add a line describing what was the problem and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running a proxy program (UltraSurf). I closed the application and re-tried and that solves my installation problem.